# need to return multiple values from NPAPI function

Tags: plugins, google-chrome, npapi

I am trying to create an NPAPI plugin where I call a javascript function and return some value from plugin. I did this by setting fields in NPVariant pointer. But since its a structure, I can put only one string at a time.
In few cases I need to return multiple values or array from NPAPI function to javascript. Any idea about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to accomplish what you want is to return a javascript array; there are two ways you can get such an array. The first (and in my opinion ideal) way is to get the window NPObject by calling NPN_GetValue and then invoke "array" and the second is to use NPN_Evaluate.

Once you have the array (it'll be an NPObject) you can invoke push on it with the items you want to add.

This is what [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) does when you return a FB::VariantList (a vector of FB::variant objects); it just creates an array, stuffs them all in, and then returns that NPObject. Thus this is a tested and reliable solution. You can also call window.object() and then SetProperty to return a javascript object; arrays area also objects, so you could even make a hybrid that is both an array (indexed) and an object (key->val).